# Spring / Hibernate : org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I need to get some data from the database and based on the result I need to execute one more query.

But I am getting below exception :

`org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1`

my code :

```
Session tempSession1 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                 Session tempSession2 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                                   Criteria criteriaApplication = tempSession1.createCriteria(Entity.class);
               try {

                    List list = criteriaApplication.add(Restrictions.eq("app__id",Entity.sys_id()).ignoreCase()).list();
                    tempSession1.flush();
                    tempSession1.close();
                    if (list.size() > 0) {


                          tempSession2.update(Entity);
                          tempSession2.flush();
                          tempSession2.close();


                     }
```

Please help. Can someone modify my code.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to do? What is `Entity` and where/how is it declared? On which row is the exception thrown?

Answer (score 0):

You get this Exception when

*the Entity in your session, which you want to update , is not up-to-date enough , according to your locking settings

*the Entity in your session, which you want to update , does not exist in the database anymore

Comment: Not necessarily, if the entity has been updated by another concurrent transaction this error would also occur.

Comment: But AFAIK it wouldn't occur on default settings , due to optimistic locking

Comment: Hm, not sure what you mean. This exception is what would be expected when using optimistic locking and another concurrent transaction had made an update to the entity.

Comment: on optimistic locking , i can make 5 threads all read the same entity , and increase a value , like read A=5 and make it A=6 , and write it all back , with no error.